# Grabar en un .txt la salida que me muestra por pantalla manteniendo el formato

Tags: php

estoy intentando que la salida que este código me muestra por pantalla lo grabe en un .txt manteniendo el formato "nombre,nota media,aprobados,suspensos".
Ejemplo de línea en el .txt: Ana,7,5,0 (solo los valores, la tabla no.)

```
    <?php
$notas = array(
'Miguel' => array('Matematicas'=>5, 'Tecnologia'=>5, 'Historia'=>6, 'Ingles'=>8),
'Ana' => array('Matematicas'=>7, 'Ingles'=>8, 'Lengua'=>6,  'Fisica'=>9, 'Historia'=>5),
'Luis' => array('Matematicas'=>4, 'Tecnologia'=>4, 'Lengua'=>5,  'Fisica'=>4, 'Historia'=>7),
'Maria' => array('Matematicas'=>6, 'Tecnologia'=>5, 'Historia'=>6, 'Ingles'=>4),
'Antonio' => array('Matematicas'=>4, 'Tecnologia'=>5, 'Lengua'=>5,  'Fisica'=>4, 'Historia'=>4, 'Ingles'=>6),
'Raul' => array('Matematicas'=>4, 'Tecnologia'=>5, 'Lengua'=>7,  'Fisica'=>5, 'Historia'=>6, 'Ingles'=>8)
);

$arrayFinal=array();

ksort($notas);
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Nombre del alumno</th><th>Nota Media</th><th>Aprobados</th><th>Suspensos</th></tr>";
foreach($notas as $nombre=>$array)
{
    
    $aprobados=0;
    $suspensos=0;
    $acumuladorNotas=0;
    $contadorNotas=0;
    $notaMedia=0;
    
    
    
    foreach($array as $asig=>$nota)
    {
    
        $contadorNotas++;
        $acumuladorNotas+=$nota;
        $notaMedia=$acumuladorNotas/$contadorNotas;         
    
        if($nota>=5)
        {
            $aprobados++;
        }
        else
        {
            $suspensos++;
        }
        
        
        $arrayFinal[$nombre]['Media'] = $notaMedia;
        $arrayFinal[$nombre]['aprobados'] = $aprobados;
        $arrayFinal[$nombre]['suspensos'] = $suspensos;
        

        
    }   
        
        echo "<tr><td>".$nombre."</td><td>".number_format($notaMedia,2)."</td><td>".$aprobados."</td><td>".$suspensos."</td></tr>";
        
}
echo "</table>";
//print_r ($arrayFinal);
ksort($arrayFinal);
$ficheroSalida=fopen("salida.txt","a");
foreach($arrayFinal as $nombres=>$array)
{   
    foreach ($array as $indice => $valor)
    {       
        fwrite($ficheroSalida,$nombres.",".$valor.PHP_EOL);
    }
}
fclose($ficheroSalida);





?>
```

he probado varias cosas como poner: $arrayFinal["aprobados"]=$aprobados; pero solo me lo guarda del primer alumno y en el .txt no me lo guarda manteniendo el formato. Espero podáis ayudarme, gracias.

Salida por pantalla:

[image: pantalla]

.txt:

[image: txt]

Update: Ahora me guarda todos los datos bien pero cuando crea el fichero .txt me repite los valores (nombre alumno) y los pone uno debajo de otro:

[image: valores]

Comment: un archivo `txt` tiene por definición un formato de **texto plano**. Si quieres mantener formato tabla, podrías usar `csv`

Comment: la tabla no es necesario, solo que muestre los valores, ejemplo: Ana,7,5,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de analizar los comentarios de tu post, intuyo que el problema lo tienes en la siguiente asignación  `$arrayFinal[$nombre]=$notaMedia;`
ya que solamente le estas asignando la `$notaMedia` de cada usuario, cuando lo que (creo) que quieres hacer es almacenar **todos** sus valores. Siendo así, es tan fácil como añadirle las `keys` al mismo array:

```
 $arrayFinal[$nombre]['Media'] = $notaMedia;
 $arrayFinal[$nombre]['aprobados'] = $aprobados;
 $arrayFinal[$nombre]['suspensos'] = $suspensos;
```

y luego iterar para imprimirlo todo en el archivo TXT. Te recomiendo descomentar la línea `//print_r ($arrayFinal);` para que veas por pantalla el contenido del array antes y así puedas autodepurar los fallos de lógica de tu código.

Te puede servir usar nombres de variables más concretos que

```
$arrayFinal as $clave=>$valor
```

Tal vez de ese modo verías como dentro de tu `$arrayFinal` estás guardando el `$nombre` del alumn@ y su `$notaMedia` y no el resto de valores que también deseas.

**UPDATE**:

Modifica tu código para que veas más claro donde está el error. En lugar de escribir directamente en el fichero con `fwrite` prueba creando una variable tipo `$linea` que contenga la línea de texto que deseas escribir en el fichero. Usa `echo` o `print_r` en tu código para cada iteración de tus bucles si es necesario.

El código que buscas quedaría algo así:

```
foreach($arrayFinal as $nombres=>$array)
{   
    $linea = $nombreAlumno . ",";
    foreach ($array as $indice => $valor)
    { 
      $linea .= $valor . ",";
    }
    $linea = substr($linea, 0, -1); //le quitamos la última coma
    print_r($linea); //compruebo que la linea tiene los datos que quiero
    //imprimo $linea en mi fichero txt
}
```

Comment: Si era eso lo que quería hacer pero ahora me guarda todos lo datos uno debajo de otro y repitiendo el nombre, lo he puesto asi: $ficheroSalida=fopen("salida.txt","a");
foreach($arrayFinal as $clave=>$array)
{ 
 foreach ($array as $indice => $valor)
 {  
  fwrite($ficheroSalida,$clave.",".$valor.PHP_EOL);
 }
 
}

Comment: Te aconsejo modificar tu pregunta, con un **UPDATE / ACTUALIZACIÓN** para que el código nuevo sea más claro de analizar y podamos responderte mejor ;)
A fin de cuentas como te decía en la respuesta, si al imprimir el `$arrayFinal` ves que tienes todos los datos que quieres, es que vas bien hasta ahí. Si no, el problema está antes. Organiza tu código para que de forma sencilla puedas identificar y debuggear el problema

Comment: actualicé la pregunta y añadí una imagen del resultado que me da.

Comment: Tu problema es conceptual de iteración con arrays. Prueba a cambiar la linea de `fwrite` por `print_r` o `echo` dentro del último bucle (`foreach($arrayFinal as $nombres=>$array)`) y modifica el código hasta que des con el problema. Ánimo que estás muy cerca! ;)

Comment: Si se que estoy cerca pero no me sale, se que en el ultimo bucle en $valor están todos los datos que se deben ir escribiendo pero no consigo que me salgan en el formato que quiero. Voy a seguir probando.

Comment: Mil gracias compañero, no se me pasaba por la cabeza crear la variable $linea para ir añadiendo los valores, funciona perfectamente!.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes simplificar un poco tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$notas = array(
            'Miguel' => array('Matematicas'=>5, 'Tecnologia'=>5, 'Historia'=>6, 'Ingles'=>8),
            'Ana' => array('Matematicas'=>7, 'Ingles'=>8, 'Lengua'=>6,  'Fisica'=>9, 'Historia'=>5),
            'Luis' => array('Matematicas'=>4, 'Tecnologia'=>4, 'Lengua'=>5,  'Fisica'=>4, 'Historia'=>7),
            'Maria' => array('Matematicas'=>6, 'Tecnologia'=>5, 'Historia'=>6, 'Ingles'=>4),
            'Antonio' => array('Matematicas'=>4, 'Tecnologia'=>5, 'Lengua'=>5,  'Fisica'=>4, 'Historia'=>4, 'Ingles'=>6),
            'Raul' => array('Matematicas'=>4, 'Tecnologia'=>5, 'Lengua'=>7,  'Fisica'=>5, 'Historia'=>6, 'Ingles'=>8)
);

ksort($notas);

$ficheroSalida = fopen("salida.txt","a");

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Nombre del alumno</th><th>Nota Media</th><th>Aprobados</th><th>Suspensos</th></tr>";

foreach($notas as $nombre => $notasAlumno) {
    $totalNotas = count($notasAlumno);
    $aprobados = count(array_filter($notasAlumno, function($nota) { if($nota >= 5) return $nota; }, 0));
    $suspensos = $totalNotas - $aprobados;
    $notaMedia = number_format(array_sum($notasAlumno) / $totalNotas, 2);

    $linea = implode(',', array($nombre, $notaMedia, $aprobados, $suspensos)) . PHP_EOL;

    fwrite($ficheroSalida, $linea);

    echo "<tr><td>".$nombre."</td><td>".$notaMedia."</td><td>".$aprobados."</td><td>".$suspensos."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

fclose($ficheroSalida);
?>
```

En tu código, por cada nota seteas el arreglo $arrayFinal (Media, aprobados, suspensos), esto lo tendrías que hacer al terminar de procesar las notas de cada alumno (o sea fuera del foreach mas anidado, donde haces el echo de la fila para la tabla).

Además directamente allí podrías escribir la linea en el archivo (en lugar de guardar los datos en el arreglo $arrayFinal), y no utilizar dos foreach después para hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, la verdad que esta mucho mejor así, voy a implementarlo.

Comment: De nada @JohnDoe!